# Entering wrong URL or refreshing in React/Express app causes all pages to error until user returns to homepage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I have an Express.js app with a React front-end. Everything works until I enter a URL for a non-existing resource (or even add a `?` to the end of an existing URL): I get a 500 "Internal server error", and then even navigating to a real URL afterward throws the same error. It will only go back to normal functioning after returning to the homepage (which makes me think the issue may be on the React side, with something I'm not understanding about single-page React apps).

The error I see on the back-end is: `TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile`, which corresponds to this bit in my code (where I point Express to the React build files):

```
app.use(express.static('../client/build'));
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('../client/build/index.html');
});
```

What's the best way of handling (or ideally, preventing) this error? Note that it doesn't crash the app, it just requires revisiting the homepage to reset things.

**EDIT**

It results in the same error even if I just refresh a (working) page.

Comment: It might help if you specify the version of Express. In some versions, using a `*` for route getting does not work as generally expected. See: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2495

Comment: use serve instead of using express .... https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/